# I can't add a simple image to react-native app

Tags: react-native, mobile

I'm trying to add an image that resides in the assets/images/ folder in react-native project but it wont render giving the following error message:

Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

The code I'm trying to make it work:

`<Image source={require('../assets/images/lockicon.png')}/>`

What should I do?

Comment: Can you share your source code?

Comment: It seems you didn‘t import Image?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path to the image is incorrect. Please check for typos and if there are none, try changing it to:

```
<Image source={require('./assets/images/lockicon.png')}/>
```

Comment: I'm sure my paths are correct, When I typed your solution I encountered a non existing file error

Comment: Can you please share full code with full error so that we can easily find out what's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set height and width to display image , please try something like this

```
<Image
style={{width: 50,height: 50}}
source={require('../assets/images/lockicon.png')}
/>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the error message did not change.